# CSS Hover works locally, but not on dev server

Tags: html, css

The hover effect I'm trying to achieve works wonderful locally, but doesn't do a thing when uploaded to our dev. environment.

Here is the HTML...

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 380px;
  line-height: 360px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #02193b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 54px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 0 10px #a09176, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.circle:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 0 20px #a09176, 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
  background-color: #01142F;
}
```

```html
<a class="circle" href="/portfolio">portfolio</a>
```

Comment: What **precisely** does "doesn't work" mean? - https://jsfiddle.net/bg39cLpc/1/

Comment: it works just fine in jsfiddle, the element responds to the hover event maybe some css rules didn't work ?

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry, should have been more specific...The box-shadow doesn't increase in size as it should, and the background color does not change.

Comment: Check if you are deploying correctly, open the web tools and go to the Resources tab and search in the CSS file, the .circle:hover selector if is there

Comment: May be browser compact issues

Comment: Caching? `CTRL + F5`

Comment: @gvee tried, even dumped the cache and did a hard reload (on chrome). still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing a similar problem in a create-react-app where my CSS :hover state on a tooltip was working locally but not when deployed.

It turns out that the minification build step was transforming my element's opacity of 100% into a 1%, so that it was never completely animating into it's final state.

Fortunately, for the opacity attribute, placing the terminating "%" is optional, so I was able to fix this omission simply by removing the trailing percent symbol.

I'm not sure why the double 00 gets removed by the minifier if the % sign is there - seems like a bug to me...

Examine your minification product to see if you might be experiencing something similar, either with your percentages or the double 00s before the ms.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies within the ordering of your CSS. As described [here](https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) you should list real properties last and the vendor prefixes first.

E.g.:

```
.circle {
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```